# laptop shut down unexpectedly cant able to view my project at Vs2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I was working on Web Project then suddenly my laptop crashed. 
Then I start my laptop again and open my project again.
Then I press F5 ASP development server start but it’s not showing my web application which I was working before laptop crashes after that I open any other web project its works but not that one which I was working.

Comment: no error nothing just press f5 and then browser with plan page

Comment: Is it going to the correct default/startup page?

Comment: i set my startup page is admin.aspx its going there but not showing anything

Comment: If you set a break point on `Page_Load` of your `admin.aspx` page does it get it or not?

Comment: no bro its not going there

Comment: @JayZee see the link in EDIT 2 of my answer, this may be your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it sounds like your file has become corrupted in this process.

However things to check are:

1. Is the code still there? Do you see anything different?
2. You could compare your code to other working web apps to identify any problems with the code.
3. Breakpoint your project to see why it is not firing, this could be done in the Page_Load

**If your code is not there:**

It is unlikely for your program to have stored a copy before your pc restarted, all I can say is if you have source control then the answer would be to look in there.

You say you were using VS2010, You could check C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\ (or the equivalent on your system).

This would only work if you have back up switched on!

**Edit**

As your code is there I would try the three points above first, then you could possibly try:

- Set the start page again
- Check web.config
- Check your route folders to ensure no files have become corrupt

I would have thought that using a breakpoint should identify to you what is going wrong.

**Edit2**

As your page_load is not firing your may want to look into this code:

[AutoEventWireUp](http://forums.asp.net/p/932513/1096656.aspx) - You need to ensure this is set to true so that it looks for Page_Load or Page_Init events.

If that fails then you may want to look into this [link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t68906-page_load-not-firing.html)

**Edit 3**

The OP has found that the app_offline.htm was activated, which what brought across the problem.

The app_offline.htm is created for when the web app is down for maintenance. So if your website was live then it would be taken down, and would show the "this site is down for maintenance message". I am not fully sure why this would have happened in your situation, however it clearly has. This is usually activated once the website is being updated and should be deleted once the update is complete. Clearly this has been a bit of an outlier for you.

Comment: i saw all code there in my files but its not showing in browser :(

Comment: i check   AutoEventWireup="true" and my code is there i dont know whats wrong i start new project and try copy each code to that new project now its working but i really want to know what wrong

Comment: Yeah, bit of a pain, not doubt something just went corrupt!

Comment: i got Vs2010 generate app_offline.htm because of that i cant able to see any thing i delete that file now my app working fine thank you

Comment: can u tell me why its generate ?

Comment: @JayZee, the app_offline.htm is created for when the web app is down for maintenance. So if your website was live then it would be taken down, and would show the "this site is down for maintenance message". I am not fully sure why this would have happened in your situation, however it clearly has. This is usually activated once the website is being updated and _should_ be deleted once the update is complete. Clearly this has been a bit of an outlier for you. Good find though! I did not think of this as your not updating. For future users please accept one of these answers,I'll add to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check in **StartMenu -> Programs -> Administrative Tools -> Run 'Event Viewer'**

Select "Windows Logs" -> System

see what error has been logged in your event viewer, typically you can see information what caused the crash or so.

Could be a memory acccess error.

Comment: Bro i just got that error at that Service stopped.

Comment: i got Vs2010 generate app_offline.htm because of that i cant able to see any thing i delete that file now my app working fine thank you all